# Merge multiple forms select option values only in one submit

Tags: php, mysql, html-select, selected

I want to merge all the option values in one click on submit button.

Like you see in next picture, i select the values in option value one by one.

[image]

Next picture have example of the final result, i want to submit in database with values given in the forms. That table is dynamic, i can remove or add more parameters in the database and select in the page.

[image]

The following code is for give the output on the top:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['menuId'];


// A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "") or die(mysql_error()); // connecta-se ao servidor
        mysql_select_db("teste") or die(mysql_error()); // selecciona a database do server escolhido

        echo "<br>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE $id = menuIdPai  ORDER BY menuId ";

$consulta = mysql_query($sql);

if ($consulta !=0) {

    echo('<table width="500px" border="1" align="center" class="tabela" cellspacing="0">');
    echo('<th class="tabela" colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">  </th>');
    echo('<tr> <td width="250px" class="ver" bgcolor="FFFFFF"> <center> Grupo/Parametro: </center> </td> <td width="350px" class="ver" bgcolor="FFFFFF"> <center> Seleccione uma opção: </center> </td> </center> '); 

    while ($mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {

    $id = $mostrar['menuId'];
    $utilizador = $mostrar['menuNome'];

    $idfilho = $mostrar['idfilho'];
// Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['menuID'] = $mostrar['menuId'];
    //echo 'userid:'.$_SESSION['menuID'];
    //echo 'sessionid:'.session_id();
    $_SESSION['menuNome'] = $mostrar['menuNome'];

{
    echo("<tr>

    <td align=\"center\" bgcolor='FFFFFF'>$utilizador</td>
    <td align=\"center\"  bgcolor='FFFFFF'> 
        <form method=\"post\" action=\"sucesso.php\"> 
        <select name='sucesso'\>;
            <option value=\"0\">0</option>;
            <option value=\"0.05\">0.05</option>;
            <option value=\"0.1\">0.1</option>;
            <option value=\"0.15\">0.15</option>;
            <option value=\"0.20\">0.20</option>;
            <option value=\"0.25\">0.25</option>;
            <option value=\"0.30\">0.30</option>;
            <option value=\"0.35\">0.35</option>;
            <option value=\"0.40\">0.40</option>;
            <option value=\"0.45\">0.45</option>;
            <option value=\"0.50\">0.50</option>;
            <option value=\"0.55\">0.55</option>;
            <option value=\"0.60\">0.60</option>;
            <option value=\"0.65\">0.65</option>;
            <option value=\"0.70\">0.70</option>;
            <option value=\"0.75\">0.75</option>;
            <option value=\"0.80\">0.80</option>;
            <option value=\"0.85\">0.85</option>;
            <option value=\"0.90\">0.90</option>;
            <option value=\"0.95\">0.95</option>;
            <option value=\"1.0\">1</option>;

        </select>

        <br><br>
        </center>


        </form>
");



 if ($idfilho == 1) 


 {

  echo "<td align=\"center\"  bgcolor='FFFFFF'>   <a href='avaliacoes2.php?menuId=".$id."'>Seleccionar</a> </td>";
 }
  else

      {

          echo "";

 }


echo    '</tr>';
}
    }



echo"</table>";






    }



    echo "<br><br><br>";


    echo ('<input type="submit" value="Submeter" class="link-style2" />');

    echo ('<br><br>');
echo ('<input type="button" value="Voltar" class="link-style2"  onclick="history.back(-1)" />');
?>`
```

And that code is for inserting in database the values i want to introduce.

That is for be done in sucesso.php.

```
<?php


{
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); // connecta-se ao servidor
        mysql_select_db("teste") or die(mysql_error()); // selecciona a database do server escolhido
        $id_resp = (isset($_POST['id_resp']) ? $_POST['id_resp'] : '');
        $corp_resp = (isset($_POST['corp_resp']) ? $_POST['corp_resp'] : '');
        $id = $_SESSION['UtilizadorID'];
        $data = (isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '');
        $menuId = (isset($_GET['menuId']) ? $_GET['menuId'] : '');

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas (id_resp, corp_resp,id,data,menuId) VALUES ('','" . $corp_resp . "','$id', NOW( ) , '$menuId')")  or die("Alguma coisa correu mal durante o registo. MySQL erro: ".mysql_error());
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo "<center>AdicIonada com sucesso.</center>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    }




    ?>
```

Foreach can be used for that case?

Thank you for all support.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the name of the select an array. Like this:

```
    <select name='sucesso[]'\>;
        <option value=\"0\">0</option>;
        <option value=\"0.05\">0.05</option>;
        <option value=\"0.1\">0.1</option>;
        <option value=\"0.15\">0.15</option>;
        <option value=\"0.20\">0.20</option>;
        <option value=\"0.25\">0.25</option>;
        <option value=\"0.30\">0.30</option>;
        <option value=\"0.35\">0.35</option>;
        <option value=\"0.40\">0.40</option>;
        <option value=\"0.45\">0.45</option>;
        <option value=\"0.50\">0.50</option>;
        <option value=\"0.55\">0.55</option>;
        <option value=\"0.60\">0.60</option>;
        <option value=\"0.65\">0.65</option>;
        <option value=\"0.70\">0.70</option>;
        <option value=\"0.75\">0.75</option>;
        <option value=\"0.80\">0.80</option>;
        <option value=\"0.85\">0.85</option>;
        <option value=\"0.90\">0.90</option>;
        <option value=\"0.95\">0.95</option>;
        <option value=\"1.0\">1</option>;

    </select>
```

Now what this does is whenever you check `$_POST['sucesso']`, it will show something like: `[0]=>0.25,[1]=>0.45,[2]=>0.65` etc...

After that you can put use it like this:

```
$array=$_POST['sucesso'];
echo $array[0]; //echoes 0.25
echo $array[1]; //echoes 0.45
echo $array[2]; //echoes 0.65
```

You can do anything with these variables. Multiply them, insert them into a database whatever you want do with it.

**Yes** Foreach can be used. In my example, foreach on the variable `$array`.

Comment: I have another doubt Loko. The location of the submit? Because if i put inside of the form loop give me submit for all and i want only one submit for all.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta You can put the submit outside of the for loop. Show me the code you're talking about. I dont see the submit.

Comment: echo "<br><br><br>";


    echo ('<input type="submit" value="Submeter" class="link-style2" />');

    echo ('<br><br>');
echo ('<input type="button" value="Voltar" class="link-style2"  onclick="history.back(-1)" />');
?>`

Comment: @ChristopheCosta Ah yes that, but that submit doesnt have to be in the loop. Just put a loop around the select tags.

Comment: I have the same opinion, the problem is not working. Is not going to sucesso.php give the result you advice. The button is obsolete now.